# Python - Compare last column in all rows of a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have read all the rows from a .csv file like this:-

```
from csv import reader, writer

# open file in read mode
with open('data.csv', 'r') as read_obj:

    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
    for row in csv_reader:
```

Now, I am trying to compare only the last column of each row in the csv file. The data in the csv file is like this:-

```
Row 1: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
Row 2: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
Row 3: 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
Row 4: 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
Row 5: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

I have to compare only the last column of each row for 1 and 0. In the last column, if there is a 1 in 1st row and a 0 in the 2nd row, then we print 1st row.

For ex 1:

```
Row 1: 0,0,1,1
Row 2: 0,1,1,0
```

Then, I print Row 1

For ex 2:

```
Row 1: 0,0,1,1
Row 2: 0,1,1,1
Row 3: 0,1,1,0
```

Then, I print Row 2

Would appreciate any suggestions for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What should the final output of your sample CSV look like? From the way I read your prompt, there are no 1's in the 2nd-to-last to column, so the last column would be unchanged.

Comment: @ZachYoung I have to compare only the last column of each row for 1 and 0. In the last column, if there is a 1 in 1st row and a 0 in the 2nd row, then we print 1st row.

Comment: So only a single row is ever printed? And it will be the second-to-last row that's printed if that row has 1 in the last column, and the last row has 0 in the last column?

Comment: And in the big example, only Row 5 is printed?

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

path = (r"data.csv")

data = pd.read_csv(path)

last_column = data.iloc[: , -1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any way to do it with the csv module?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.  It shows you how to:

1. read your input rows, convert from `'1'` and `'0'` to `1` and `0`, and store the row
2. look up the last and second-to-last rows
3. compare the last columns of those two rows

```py
import csv

all_rows = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as in_f:
    reader = csv.reader(in_f)

    # Read all rows and convert columns from string to int
    for row in reader:
        all_rows.append([int(col) for col in row])

last_row = all_rows[-1]
previous_row = all_rows[-2]

if previous_row[-1] == 1 and last_row[-1] == 0:
    with open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_f:
        writer = csv.writer(out_f)
        writer.writerow(previous_row)
```

When I run that on **Ex 1**:

```
0,0,1,1
0,1,1,0
```

I get:

```
0,0,1,1
```

On **Ex 2**:

```
0,0,1,1
0,1,1,1
0,1,1,0
```

I get

```
0,1,1,1
```

And on the big example:

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

I get Row 4:

```
0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

Comment: Oh, did it work?

Comment: No, I am using pandas for now but will take this answer into consideration for later use. Thanks.